# Как в Android Studio закрепить положение component tree?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Так получилось, что после некоторых действий с android studio элемент component tree стал небольшим независимым окошком с возможностью передвижения, подскажите, пожалуйста, как закрепить его обратно (под элемент Palette)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо сделать следующее:

1. нажать на *шестеренку* (справа от текста *Component Tree*);
2. выбрать *Attached Side*;
3. найти вкладку *Left* и выбрать ее.

После этого компонент встанет на прежнее место.

[image: Фотография действий:]